# Font used on Narcos show

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Does anyone know the font used in the beginning of Narcos TV show?

[image]

myfonts.com identifies it as Gothic but it is not Gothic. whatfontis.com gives a bunch of font suggestions but the letter **a** and **m** are different.

Comment: Hi Nick. Welcome to GDSE! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: I tried many what font sites but they all turn to no result.

Comment: Just to prevent obsolete suggestions: what are those close-but-not-close enough fonts then?

Comment: I'm 98% sure it's Helvetica, but you probably already know

Answer (score 3):

Feels too much like a "Neue Haas Grotesk" to me, I dont have illustrator to closely check the pixels but it must be Neue haas or some really close alternative, maybe stretched up to 5/10%~.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think its [Usual Medium](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/r-type/usual/medium/) font with the reference image
[image]